# Reply, Reply All button on Email Message throwing error to community users

Tags: community, case, emailmessage

We have a community setup for our customers from where they create cases, and on the case detail page, we have a related list for emails. In the related list, when users navigate to the email message record, they can see the options Reply and Reply All. However, when they click on these buttons, they encounter the error shown in the screenshot. How can this be resolved? Basically I want to give community users an ability to reply on the email from the community itself.[image]

Comment: Go Setup > Open Developer console and then reproduce that same error. 

Post the debug logs to this forum then we can "look under the hood"